# Cloud function some time throw error The request was aborted because there was no available instance

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I using cloud function and some time cloud function throw error message:

> The request was aborted because there was no available instance

This situation has increased in recent times. I know that this is a scale instance issue at google. Is there any other way to completely fix this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you dealing with this across multiple regions or a specific one?

Comment: I only used cloud function one region.

Comment: @luisvenezian I used cloud function 2 year but recents times error increment. I don't know it problem base infra or not ?

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur due to two different reasons as mentioned in the [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability)

1. This happens when the Cloud Functions infrastructure is not able to scale up instances fast enough to handle the incoming load.
2. This happens when you have set a limit for the maximum number of instances and if there are no instances available to handle the incoming request.

To avoid this error either you can redeploy your Cloud Functions in a different region if possible. Also you can implement [retries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) as it is a best practice.

I have also found this [Google’s issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/218684739) where the Google team is working on it.

Comment: I can't deploy  multiple region because my user only on one region. Not global.  I using Cloud Functions two year but recently this error appears more and more

Comment: In which region are you receiving this error?

Comment: I using asia-northeast1

Comment: I suggest raising a [Google Cloud Support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) as it may require internal debugging, and knowing where the problem might be. You can refer this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/962) as well and go through it

Comment: @BaoTrungTran: Did you start a ticket and if so, did you get a resolution? I'm experiencing the same thing and have almost no load whatsoever. It's all the time now on a certain firestore update.